# Select by location QGIS and PostGIS. Exception: unknown

Tags: qgis, postgis, select-by-location

Are there some limitations in feature number, while making spatial query in QGIS?

All my data is in PostGIS format. When testing with a small amount of features, it works perfectly, but with 1032862 polygon features only this error message returned.

> Uncaught error while executing algorithm
>               Traceback (most recent call last):
>                 File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
>                   self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>                 File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\SelectByLocation.py", line 94, in processAlgorithm
>                   index = vector.spatialindex(inputLayer)
>                 File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\vector.py", line 220, in spatialindex
>                   idx = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures(request))
>               Exception: unknown

Comment: Check the geometry validity of the layers... Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Validity

Comment: Did you perhaps try to perform the query purely through sql?

Comment: not yet, will try soon.

Comment: Just check the geometry, there were many errors, correct almost all of them, but still have 3 errors, with "Unknown geometry type 0" message and located on 0,0 coordinate. I Don't know how to correct it.

Comment: already correct all geometry errors, but same result :(